# Exploit CVE-2020-0688 for older versions

Tags: cve, exchange, deserialization

I wanted to exploit my IIS [CVE-2020-0688](https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-US/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2020-0688), which I saw that the key is the same as advertised.

The problem is that my IIS is old, and uses AppPool of .NET 2 and not .NET 4. Also I can use only GET as I don't see a POST request using the viewstate. All the exploits in ysoserial use `Microsoft.PowerShell.Editor.dll` which is not loaded in the old version.

Does anyone know a gadget for .NET2?